# Create polyphonic dsp node in audiokit 5

Tags: signal-processing, audiokit, faust

I am searching for the resources to create a polyphonic dsp node in audiokit 5, so that I can connect and use it with AudioEngine. For c++ dsp, I am using faust.

AudioKit with faust single voice node is working for me by using [faust2audiokit](https://github.com/grame-cncm/faust/tree/master-dev/architecture/audiokit) (audiokit 5.0.1), but didn't got any success with polyphonic node.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the DSP nodes, but the AudioKit Oscillators are monophonic. For polyphonic synths they recommend using the DunneAudioKit Synth class. There is a polyphonic oscillator example in the AudioKit Cookbook but it basically is a round-robin Oscillator pool.

Comment: I have checked DunneAudioKit Synth class, but it has lots dependencies and its confusing to implement.

Is there any way to use faust polyphonic dsp, (monophonic working fine using faust2audiokit) to  just trigger keyOn( )